# How to increase ringtone volume from low to high from Android application

Tags: android, ringtone, android-audiomanager

Does anybody know if there is a way to set incoming call ringtone volume increasing from low to high programmatically from Android application?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: And where is your code? what have you tried?

Comment: Actually, I don't have it because I wasn't sure if such feature is realizable in Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call to getStreamMaxVolume(RingTone) to get your max volume of the ring tone.

```
    int streamMaxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(streamMaxVolume), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Now you have your max volume.

Then you could make some method to change the volume (with a timer, loop, random, ...)

```
 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,**YOURVOLUMEHERE**,
 AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) 
Try this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
```